# react js lodash filter conditional filter attribute

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I am trying to figure out how to change the filter attribute on a collection

Here is my code so far

```
_.filter(
  myCollection, 
  {Category: "Name", Year: "2020", IsActive: true}).map(
     record => (
      // ... my code 
     )
  )
)
```

I like to conditionally change the Category string,

I tried

```
Category: "Name" || "Address" // but this did not work
```

I want to avoid two long statement with one for Category: "Name" and another filter for Category: "Address"

I also tried

```
Category: categoryConditionString // blank or Name orAddress but this did not work
```

Is there a way to allow Category to be assigned something that will allow it to bring back all the record for all categories, or category = name or category = address?

Thanks

Comment: Will you show us your expected outcome and what you're currently getting?
Also, in `Category: "Name" || "Address"` the string `Name` is always truthy so it will never get past that.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out, got the following working

_.filter(
  myCollection, 
  this.FilterForName ? {Category: "Name", Year: "2020", IsActive: true}
                     : {Category: "Address", Year: "2020", IsActive: true}

).map(
     record => (
      // ... my code 
     )
  )
)

Answer (score -1):

```
_.filter(
  myCollection, 
   obj => (obj.Category === "Name" || obj.Category === 'Address') && Year === "2020" && IsActive }).map(
     record => (
      // ... my code 
     )
  )
)
```

Read more about the filter function [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter)